# Removing a release folder with an invalid character

Tags: azure-devops

At some point we managed to create a folder in our releases that starts with an '@' character. This is not a valid character, but didn't trigger any errors:

[image: Example of the situation]

Now I'd like to get rid of it because we don't have a use for it. But when I try to remove the folder I get this exception:

> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.InvalidPathException: The string argument contains a character that is not valid:'@'. Correct the argument, and then try the operation again.

I've tried removing the folder use the browser interface and using the REST API

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The string argument contains a character that is not valid:'@'. Correct the argument, and then try the operation again.\r\nParameter name: path",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.InvalidPathException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common",
    "typeKey": "InvalidPathException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

So both result in the same exception.

Is there a way to still delete this folder?

Comment: That folder "in your releases" comes from something. Source control, a build artifact, a step in the release definition... somewhere. Fix the problem at the root.

Comment: @DanielMann That's not the problem I'm having. This folder exists on the release pipeline overview. I've added a screenshot to clarify.

Comment: That clarifies it. Your wording suggested it was a folder **in the file system**.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you thought that. That's why I added the screenshot for extra clarification. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, you need to go to the [DC forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to feedback your problem. Engineer in DC will do the data fix (change the folder name) in our database i.e we need to rename the folder which has invalid character '@'.  Then you can delete this folder with invalid character.

In the follow-up,please share the below details so that the engineer can fix it for you.

**Details required:**

1.Account name

2.Project name

3.Folder name (which has invalid character)

4.New Folder name (without invalid characters)

To protect your privacy, please choose "viewable by Microsoft Only" in the follow-up.

You can refer to this [case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/417422/renaming-release-pipeline-folder-allows-invalid-ch.html) with the same issue.